# High ping when playing any game

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, lag

Currently, I am using a TP-Link AV-4220 as my powerline as my room is the furthest away from the main router. I am connected to it through an ethernet cable. I use Virgin Media as my ISP, but they are known for not being the best.

Recently (just now for some reason) I've realized that when launching any game (eg. Rainbow Six Siege), I gain mass amounts of ping. This hasn't happened to me before, it's only just happened. When I don't have a game open, my internet is stable. Also, this only happens in games, doesn't occur during discord calls (high CPU usage = high ping?)

Below is a screenshot of my command prompt and what I did.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: do you actually have issues in the games you are playing?  What if you try google dns or your ISPs?

Comment: 1. Google 'bufferbloat', which will likely lead you away from using wifi extenders, then 2. Use Virgin's own default DNS servers, which will likely be much faster for most things.

Comment: Mistake, I mean powerline. Also, I was using Virgin's DNS servers, but it still leads to the same issues as mentioned.

Comment: its possible that the router, the powerline adapters, or your local NIC cannot keep up if there is a bunch of other traffic, and pressure on your CPU could be the problem as well. I'd be inclined to blame the powerline adapters as I've never thought they were trustworthy, but that may be my bias.

Comment: I mean, they're from TP-Link, so I would generally trust the powerline. However, the issue just started today - I would doubt it would be a CPU issue as it has (mostly) worked in the past month.

Comment: The next step in troubleshooting this for me would be to see if your ping is high when also pinging your router's IP; if it is, this validates the issue is purely local to your machine. You can then try running a CPU load tester to see if it occurs and a GPU load tester to see if you can narrow the problem further. If your ping is not high to the local router, try pinging 1.1.1.1 from another device while you have a high ping on this device, it could be something on your machine that is thrashing your internet connection while in these games.

Comment: @AdamLark It's definitely a powerline or Virgin Media problem, checked the ping both on my phone and on my computer. It doesn't seem to be related to my computer.

Comment: What's funny is that this happens in periods: one time the high latency stops and maybe a few days later, it comes up with the same issue.